# kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, xelatex

I am getting errors while exporting the notebook as a pdf, Am using RHEL-7.9 and running jupyter lab with python 3.6, and following the [documentation to install dependencies](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

I tried almost everything but did not find the solution.

> Error:
>
> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
> Failed to run "['xelatex', 'notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
> restricted \write18 enabled.
>
> pathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
>
> I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!

Comment: after executing this command `sudo yum install texlive` now I am getting bellow error.               ! LaTeX Error: File `tcolorbox.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.4     \usepackage
                   {parskip} % Stop auto-indenting (to mimic markdown behavi...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer led me towards the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-install-tex-live-on-centos-7-linux/

yum update

yum install perl

yum install perl-Digest-MD5

wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz

cd install-tl-20211117

sudo -s

./install-tl
After that you will see some text, It will ask about Input you can select (I)  as option.

vi ~/.bashrc

export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc

yum install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use the `I` option when executing `install-tl`. That will lead to a 6 GB+ installation and a long installation process. Maybe better follow this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397181/243557 That will just use 110 MB. Needed packages can then later be installed manualy.

And as a note: to abort the `install-tl`: keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> pressed (or point me out to a better way :D)